# What are the pros and cons of using session variables to manage a users session data?

Tags: asp.net, session, variables, caching, viewstate

Using **ASP.NET** I have always used session variables to maintain a users session data.

Typically: *(Coded as simple bools/ints with around 12 total variables)*

- User information.
- Page security permissions.

I have read increasing information regarding the negative effects of using session variables.
I am aware that session variables are stored in memory and the negative effects that using too many can have; this is not the desired scope of this question.

---

**What I would like to know:**

Using **current** development languages and features:

- Do session variables pose a security risk?
  *(By security risk I mean is it possible to read / alter variables)*
- Is there better performance using **querystrings**, **viewstate**, **caching**, or making **database request** on every page load?
- What is *"considered"* good practice for handling a users session data. *(All topics relating to this subject are now very old and perhaps no longer relevant)?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A performance is always something subjective and may vary depending on different things. In your case you're trying to compare incomparable because

- querystrings cannot be used to share sensitive user information or page security, because everyone can modify urls directly in the browser
- viewstate is set and maintained on the page level. It cannot be carried across different page requests, only on postbacks of the current page.
- caching is done on the application level, and all users can access it. It might work in case of page security permissions but not applicable to store individual user information.

Making database requests is the only comparable option and yes, it's slower than a session. This is where you can try to play with viewstate and caching and try improve performance and reduce a database workload.

Sessions are stored in a memory on the server but depend on cookies and in theory, it's possible to hijack the session by stealing the asp.net session cookie.

> SessionID values are sent in clear text. A malicious user could get
>   access to the session of another user by obtaining the SessionID value
>   and including it in requests to the server. If you are storing
>   sensitive information in session state, it is recommended that you use
>   SSL to encrypt any communication between the browser and server that
>   includes the SessionID value.

Quote: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Bottom line: using sessions is secure but to make it more secure use HTTPS

ASP.NET provides out of the box functionality for user authentication, role based authorization and user profiles which might make sense to use. Read more about profiles:  [How to use Profile in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888264/how-to-use-profile-in-asp-net) and  [Regarding Profile and session in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088771/regarding-profile-and-session-in-asp-net) There is a lot of other topics and answers here on this site regarding authentication and authorization.

Comment: This is the best answer provided for the question asked but did not offer the full information I was hoping for. So can I ask: What do you recomend as a good alternative?

Comment: If security is your concern then using a session is secure enough and I'd keep using it. However, this is not an asp.net way and as I mentioned above there is out-of-the-box functionality e.g. forms authentication which you might consider as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> Do session variables pose a security risk? (By security risk I mean is it possible to read / alter variables)

Although, as smirnov quoted, a malicious user might get accrss to another user's session by hijacking the session itself, the session variables themselves are stored at **server-side**, and cannot be accessed directly.

> Is there better performance using querystrings, viewstate, caching, or
>   making database request on every page load?

As smirnov wrote, the comparison isn't exactly valid. However, consider:

- querystrings and viewstate are **stored in the http request**, therefore are both less secure and consume no memory. However, they will take some minor processing power to parse.
- Caching (in the web-server RAM) the results of previous database request will lighten the load on the database and the network connections between your web-server and the DB server, and will also retrieve the data faster. However, they will obviously use more RAM on the web-server itself.

> What is "considered" good practice for handling a users session data.
>   (All topics relating to this subject are now very old and perhaps no
>   longer relevant)?
>   Since the principles haven't changed much, the existing sources, IMHO **should still be relevant.**

Note: If you're using multiple servers, you'll need to synchronize the session data across them, by using a state-server, for example, or use "sticky sessions", in which each session is always served by the same server.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should avoid sessions as much as possible. Here are my reasons in no particular order.

- Sessions doesn't scale automatically when you add more nodes (Sure you can use a dedicated session-server but that comes with some overhead)
- When you have enabled sessions each user can only make a single request at the same time. Asp.net implements per user locking if the session is enabled to avoid any race conditions. This is mostly a problem in if you use a lot of ajax.
- If you have to restart the webserver the user lose their session. This is really the main point for me. It really sucks to have a system where people risk to get kicked out, get a corrupted session or simply lose progress because you need to deploy a bugfix. Avoiding session as much as possible gives you much more freedom and a better experience for your user.

It's up to you but I always try to either store the data in a persistent store or use something that actually exist in the web (cookies, querystring, writing state to a hidden field etc etc). I bet there are situations where I would use sessions but my default choice is to avoid them.

Comment: Session state is not loss on recycle if you use the StateServer or SqlServer (or the Azure one) for storing session (same for lock). When working with the session, you should always validate your dev using StateServer or SqlServer, never the Inproc state store which may lead to incorrect conclusion about scalability & performance of your application.

Answer (score 1):

These days there are more options:

- Local Storage / Session Storage / Page Javascript Variable - are good for client-side storage situations. see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp. But they wouldn't be suitable for most trust situations, not without server-side signing. A javascript variable will be lost upon page restart, but persist in browser Session Storage if it was written there. If that browser tab is closed, the Session Storage is lost, but persist in the Local Storage if it was written there.
- JSON Web Tokens (JWT) - are the emerging new standard for replacing Sessions. This is a standard for authentication, roles, data, and claims, which is signed by the server, and can also be encrypted to the client can't read any of the details. This is usually stored in Local Storage by the client, and only really works for Single Page Applications which can write to the Bearer header. Don't use this for MVC (MVC.Controller) with server-side generation of HTML. JWTs can be a pain to set up and customise - the API for OWIN is terribly sparse. JWTs can get big too, which means you're always "uploading" the JWT data upon each Request to the web-server. But JWTs enable your security to be handled by one server (even an externally trusted server).
- ASP.Net Server-Side Sessions - Can be in-memory in-proc, in-memory external-proc, and database.

Answering your specific questions:

1. Security risk - Not really. The session uses a key that's long enough that it can't be guessed. It's typical to use HTTPS these days, so that value is securely transmitted. The variables are stored only on the server, with a set per user. If a user's device is compromised, it's possible to steal the session key, but if their device is compromised, there are bigger problems to deal with.
2. Performance is not better or worse for "query strings", "view state", or "caching" compared to In-Proc (Memory) sessions. They're all in the realms of speed of memory (RAM) - nanoseconds. Database (disk stored) is certainly slower, because the medium access time is slower - milliseconds
3. Sessions are good practice. Some would recommend having a dedicated class for reading and storing each variable (using Properties), so you don't get the session variable names (strings) confused.

I am a fan of a possible hybrid approach to Sessions. see [How can I store Session information in a hybrid (Database + Memory) way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922302/how-can-i-store-session-information-in-a-hybrid-database-memory-way)