# How can I store Session information in a hybrid (Database + Memory) way?

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, session-state

Memory is good for speed, but is limited, and therefore requires session time limits which then discard the session information permanently.

Database is good for volume storage and catering for more users concurrently and having longer session times. But the increased latency per request is a significant overhead.

How can I configure ASP.Net to use an SQL Database (or other database for that matter), and cache the most recent used Session data in memory?

It would seem there is no inbuilt configuration option ready to go.

Update:

- By "Session" I refer to the server-side Session store: `var userID = Session["UserID"]`

Comment: Are you talking about client side caching in the browser, server side caching in the web server or database caching? SQL Server already transparently uses memory for this purpose. ASP.Net already has caching decorations to define web server or client side caching.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The context is for "Session" not OutputCaching. Being Asp.net tagged, it's about server-side, not client-side. But I will update the question to be clearer.

Comment: It looks like MS haven't included this kind of thing by default which is strange (because it would be so easy to do, and could functionally replace the external-process option)